# cannot ping domain name, ping IP's work

Tags: ubuntu-server

but if I ping IP of domain name it's works

this my /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

ping google.com
ping: unknown host google.com

ping 8.8.8.8
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=30.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=30.3 ms

FYI
Ubuntu Server 14.04

Comment: This should answer your question. 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/465729/ping-unknown-host-google-com-in-ubuntu-server

Comment: `resolv.conf`file is not persistent, but could be resolving the domains. please check if `nslookup google.com 8.8.8.8` which will try to resolve `google.com` with `8.8.8.8` name server. If you do not specify the server `nslookup google.com` the nslookup output will give you the default name server.

Comment: when I tried to nslookup google.com, I found ";; connection timed out; no servers could be reached"

Comment: [solved], my ISP requires the use of certain DNS, doesn't use 8.8.8.8 as dns-nameservers